I want to change the default settings on my toolbar
I'm trying to upload my CSV from my local file but my CSV on the toolbar is set to open CSV remotely and is default.
I tried to access the toolbar and change the settings but is always remotely. I also tried to customize my toolbar and change the settings but got to no avail

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
